# The eurika service is it necessray in implementing a microservice?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix

I want to create a microservice with spring boot but in fact I am not underestanding the architecture microservice well ! I create a controller, a service, a repository, a model and I have related it with a mongo database thanks to the file application.properties ! And I can access to it thanks to the path "http://localhost:8080".
**My question is : This project that I have developped with spring boot is it a microservice ? Or it need the service Eurika to become a microservice ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question - to understand the answer you need to think first "*Why microservices*" or "*What are the benefits of microservices*".

When you will google this you will get tons of [benefits of microservices architecture](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) (of course there are some drawbacks as well).

But focusing on benefits one of the most common benefits you will see is microservices architecture is scalable.

Now the answer to your questions lies in this benefit '**Scalable**'.
In very simple words, scalability of microservices means *horizontal scalability* of the microservices. That essentially means you need to run multiple instances of your microservices so that you can cater more and more load/traffic on your system.
Now the moment you run multiple instances there has to be some support component in your architecture that helps you in [service discovery](https://microservices.io/patterns/server-side-discovery.html).

And Eureka is one of the ways you do service discovery in the microservices services architecture.

Now the short answer to your question - No! Eureka is not necessary microservices architecture **but service discovery is one of the foundation pattern in the microservices architecture.** (and Eureka is one of the tool/ways of achieving the same)